# CPO with a top element that is not a complete lattice?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

This has been bothering me for a while. I have been convinced that such examples exist but cannot come up with one.

Basically I have been playing with different posets, for eg elements arranged as nodes in a hexagon (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Counter-examples) similar to the counter example here. But cannot figure it out exactly.

Any help and pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that by CPO you mean a [Complete partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_partial_order), which some define as a poset in which every directed set has a supremum (this is the first definition in the linked Wikipedia article).
Since every finite poset is directed-complete (see first example in linked page), it is enough to take a finite poset with top element (and bottom, if you will) that is not a lattice.

---

By the way, one concrete example is the pic. 7 in your linked page.

Comment: By CPO I mean what you say. Could you please explain what is meant by $M_{3}\{1}$.

Comment: @jamie Sorry, I just noticed that you're asking for cpo **with** top element. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @jamie So $M_3 \setminus \{1\}$ was the lattice $M_3$ without its top element (the lattice $M_3$ was in the linked page; not anymore).

Comment: Thanks. But, CPOs are supposed to have a least upper bound, which pic 7 does not have, if I am right.

Comment: @jamie You are wrong. Check the Wikipedia page. In CPOs, *directed sets* have a supremum, not every set. That is, every set in which every pair has a common upper bound must have a supremum, not an arbitrary subset.

Comment: So, does something like the figure in the link seem ok?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/je5cld4aob1utov/cpo.png?dl=0

Comment: @jamie Yes, that's ok. More generally, notice that **any** finite poset is a CPO. For example, the pictures 7 and 8 in the page you linked to are finite posets which are not lattices; and so is the one in picture 6, but that one doesn't have a top element. Anyway this other one in the picture you linked from the dropbox is yet another finite poset which is not a lattice, because, for example, the set of upper bounds of $\{e,f\}$ is $\{a,b,c\}$, with minimal elements $b$ and $c$, and thus no minimum element (which would be the supremum of $\{e,f\}$).

Comment: Thanks. It's clearer now.